# MySQL Ignore Contiguous Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

If I had a table that read like this:

```
|id|val|
|--|---|
|1 |a  |
|2 |b  |
|3 |b  |
|4 |c  |
|5 |b  |
```

Is there a purely MySQL method to generate the following result:

```
|id|val|
|--|---|
|1 |a  |
|2 |b  |
|4 |c  |
|5 |b  |
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(id), val FROM ... GROUP BY val;` ... ?

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. It will exclude the row (5, b), which you can see he wants in his output.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done using lag window function but MySQL doesn't support this. There is however a workaround using variables:

```
SET @val=null;
select id, curr_val as val from (
   select id, @val prev_val, @val:=val curr_val
     from tbl
) where curr_val != prev_val;
```